# sitefinity widget using query string

Tags: sitefinity

I like to build a widget that will take in the query string as parameters. Is there a build in method for this in sitefinity? Or is this something I have to do in code? I like to leverage sitefinity toolset .

`domain.com/shoes?type=sneakers&sort=price_ascending`

```
namespace SitefinityWebApp.Mvc.Controllers
{
    [ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "Shoes", Title = "Shoes", SectionName = "MVC")]
    public class ShoesController : Controller
    {
        public string type{ get; set; }
        public string sort{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should take in routed parameters like a regular MVC controller.  So like

```
public ActionResult Index(string type, string sort){
 this.sort = sort;
 this.type = type;
 ....
}
```

There's nothing to automatically hydrate those public properties (and thank god, can you imagine the havok if someone could change them arbitrarily?)

But you can use Telerik.Sitefinity.Services.SystemManager.CurrentHttpContext to get the HTTP context that has the regular Request.Querystring to use.

Think of Sitefinity more as like a regular ASP.NET MVC site, with API helpers instead of a magic "do it the sitefinity way" kinda thing you know :)  The ability to have multiple controllers on a page is GREAT.

Comment: Is there a way to call different ActionResult method? and not the default